# Does an IDE update when pulling files from a repository

Tags: android, android-studio, github

This might be a simple question about GitHub but I couldn't get a straight-forward answer anywhere. I noticed that when I pull files from GitHub down, the files change in explorer.

I'm wondering if I've opened a project in Android Studio, pulled the changed/added/deleted files from GitHub in, will the project in Android Studio updates? Can I do that when I'm running (Shift+F10, not instant run) the app and the IDE is installing the app to the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is YES because that's Git's purpose since it's a Version Control System (VCS) and it aims to keep all the developers on the team up to date and aware of all the changes made in a project. Every time you pull (unless your local repository is not up to date) the changes will be made in your app's local folder. Say you  have an android studio project that is linked to a repository on Github. When you make changes to the project on your computer, all you need to do is do a `git push` and the changes will be saved on the correspondent GitHub repository. But if someone on your team pushes a new NewActivity.java on the project from their computer, and you execute a `git pull` command, the NewActivity.java will certainly be present in you android studio project unless there's a problem in the connection between your android project and the Github repository. As for your second question, I  don't see the reason why that can't be done since you  can already add files in your  android project even if the IDE is installing the app to the device. However since Android studio doesn't support Hot Reloading you will only be able to see the version of the app that was launched before pulling from Github. To view the newly pulled version all you need to do is is re-run the app on your emulator or android device from Android studio when pulling is finished. You can try that manually by adding/editing files directly from Github. 
https://git-scm.com/doc contains some nice details and provides some real world examples on how projects can be managed, updated and even saved from destruction with Git. I hope my answer was helpful to you.